# Copy the rows from one workbook to another in Excel having specific column value

Tags: python, excel

I have created a sheet in Excel with columns being Sr.No.,date, subject, action. The last column 'action' has only two values ie. `completed` and `pending`. There are 'n' number of rows. What I want is that the rows with its last column having value `pending` should be written to another workbook by creating a new workbook.
I am getting an error with the following code

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:/Users/admin/Documents/omkar.xlsx')

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

i=0

data = [sheet.cell_value(0<i<i++, col) if sheet.Ei = 'pending' 

sheet.cell_value(i, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols) else increment i]

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()

sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for index, value in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(i, index, value)

workbook.save('C:/Users/admin/Documents/om.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use Excel for this?????

```
Sub mySales()

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 2) = "Pending" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\test.xlsx"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run this code in python I get an error in the first line. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This script runs in Excel, not in Python.  Open Excel, hit Alt+F11, paste the code into the window that opens, adjust the filename to point to your specific source file, and hit F5.